# How to Handle multiple Ajax call calling same function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-service, angular-http

Hi have 4 directives on the page, all directive require list of user.
User List is stored in database which require hhtp request.
As 4 directive are on the page at same time so 4 different ajax call has been sent to server for similar response.

And then the response is getting cached.

What can be done that all 4 directive recieves its user list and only one ajax is sended to server.

Code Inside Directive(self is this) (ajaxCallService is service)

```
ajaxCallService.getUser(function(response) {
                self.users = response;
                //Next operations
});
```

ajaxCallService Service

```
Variable
var userList = []

Method
if (!userList.length) {
          $http.post({
                url: #,
                data:#
            })
            .then(
                function(response) {
                        userList = response.allMembers;
                        callback && callback(userList);
                }
            );
        }else{
            callback && callback(userList);
        }
```

How can i prevent 4 ajax calls and only make 1 call and let other 3 wait for the response and pass response back?

Comment: Use angular promises.

Comment: call each ajax functions inside the callback of previous one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use promises for this, to see if it is already running. Because services are singletons in angular, you know it is always a shared instance:

```
var userList = [];
var promise;

function getUser() {
    // inject the $q service
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    if (userList.length) {
        // already got data, immediately resolve that one
        deferred.resolve(userList);
    }

    if (promise) {
        // a promise is already working on it, return this one
        return promise;
    } else {
        $http.post(...).success(function(response) {
            userList = response;
            deferred.resolve(response);
        });
    }

    // if this point is reached, this is the first call
    // assign the promise so other calls can know this one is working on it
    promise = deferred.promise;
    return promise;
}
```